# How would I create a new object from a class using a for loop in java?

Tags: java, class, for-loop, instance

I have a class named Card and I have this for loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    Card cardNameHere = new Card();
}
```

What I want to do is create new instances based on the for loop.  So for example, I would like the names to be card1, card2, card3, etc.  The number would come from the for loop.

I have tried this and it does not seem to work:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    Card card[i] = new Card();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

---

So I am using the solution from Hovercraft Full Of Eels, but I have another problem.

I am using cardList.add(new Card()); , and when I try to use Card(i) to set the name, java won't let me do it. Using it without i works fine, but how do I access it so I can call another method on it such as setId. I would like to call cardName.setId();

Comment: The 2nd approach is going down the right path, but you want to declare an *Array of Cards*, say `Card[] cards = new Card[13]` outside the loop. Then you can assign each (new) card to the array, `cards[i] = new Card()` in the loop.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use variable variables. It's much better to use a collection and access each element by index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your array *before* the loop, and fill it *inside* the loop. Better to use an ArrayList though.

```
List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
for (i = 0; i < MAX_CARD; i++) {
  cardList.add(new Card());
  // or new Card(i) as the case may be
}
```

If you're filling a deck of cards, and you have your Suit and Rank enums nicely created, then:

```
List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) {
  for (Rank rank: Rank.values()) { 
    cardList.add(new Card(suit, rank));
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> So I am using cardList.add(new Card()); , and when I try to use Card(i) to set the name, java won't let me do it. Using it without i works fine, but how do I access it so I can call another method on it such as setId. I would like to call the cardName.setId();

`Card(i)` doesn't make sense as you can't treat the Card class as if it were a method -- again I'm not even sure what to make of it, what you're trying to do here. If you need to extract a Card from the ArrayList, you will need to call the `get(...)` method on the ArrayList, here called `cardList`. Better still would be to set the Card properties in its constructor as I show in my 2nd code snippet.

Comment: Everyone has helped me so far, but this answer is closest to what I am working on. I already have an ArrayList but did not know that this could be done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, variable names have to be known at compile-time.  Even in other languages like JavaScript, where that is not true, it is a good idea to not try to dynamically create variables at runtime.

This is exactly what arrays are meant to solve: when you have items of a known type, but unknown quanity at compile time.  You need to declare the card as an array: `Card[] cards`

```
Card[] cards = new Card[13];
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i] = new Card();
}
```

Notice I changed the for loop to loop through to cards.length, which is figured out at runtime, so that 13 does not have to be hard-coded in both places.